# How to get event by event id into fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

How is possible get and event by the event id of fullcalendar bootstrap?

I have the event id and I want get the event from this. 
I'm trying this:

```
var evento = $("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'clientEvents')[response.idEvent];
```

response.idEvent is the id event, this is correct (for example '32' from my mysql database), I know this because I print this and is correct, but I don't know how to get the event from this...

How can get this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

According to the [FullCalendar's documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/clientEvents/), you can achieve what you want by doing:

```
var evento = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('clientEvents', response.idEvent);
```

The brackets in the documentation mean that the parameter is optional.

Comment: But, if I print this or show with alert(evento), I get: "[object Object], [object Object]"...  How can refresh this event if I get [object Object]?? Thanks!

Comment: I mean if I get "[object Object], [object Object]".. isn't the event, are some events. How can get the event if the id is unique??

Comment: @user3745888 That happens because it's a jQuery plugin, so it returns a jQuery object. You must use `evento[0]` to get the event itself.

Comment: Do you know why I get undefined, if I add var evento = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('clientEvents', response.idEvent)[0]; ?? And I get the same ([object Object]..) if I write evento[0] ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want just get all properties of event you can add the [0] and choose properties through dot. For example you have event id as "_fc1" (got it from http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.4.0/demos/agenda-views.html):

```
var eventoObj = $("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'clientEvents', "_fc1")[0];
var evento_allDay = eventoObj._allDay;
var evento_start = eventoObj._start;
var evento_end = eventoObj._end;
```

etc.